# Validity of □(P→ Q) → (◊P → ◊Q) in linear temporal logic

Tags: logic, linear-temporal-logic

How can I prove that $\Box(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\Diamond P\rightarrow\Diamond Q)$ is valid in linear temporal logic (LTL)?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Temporal_operators

Comment: @DavidRicherby, thank you for your reference. As for your answer, it is intuitively clear that if P->Q is Globally true, then when at some future moment P becomes true then Q will be/become true. However, with the axioms I cannot prove the statement. In particular, I can't find a rule that G->F.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The question says nothing about axioms. I argued (informally) that every model of $\Box(P\to Q)$ is also a model of $Diamond P\to\Diamond Q$, which means that everything is a model of the implication.

Comment: @DavidRicherby. Ah. With "proof" I was looking for a formal proof.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie So make my informal proof formal. And... are you the asker? If so, please merge your accounts. It's really confusing to post stuff under two completely different names.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, no, I am not the poster, just (re)learning a lot. As said, I couldn't find the inference rule G(P) -> F(P) in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what the formula means. The first part says that it's always true that $P$ implies $Q$; the second part says that, if $P$ is true somewhere, then $Q$ must be true somewhere, too. Well, if $P$ implies $Q$ then, if $P$ is true somewhere, then $Q$ had better be true in that place, too!

Comment: Can u be more specific? I know the meaning of the formula. But i dont know how to prove second part from the first one. Thx

Comment: @zhouziyao Actually, this answer contains exactly the proof idea, just written down slightly informally (but with all non-trivial steps included). Now, you only need to put this into formal notation and you have a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Take this with a grain of salt, since I'm not sure what sort of inference rules you're allowed to use. Assuming the domain D is times t with standard ordering, I'd say:

1. □(P→Q)
   Assume for conditional proof, i.e. P→Q is true at any t in D
2. ◊P
   Assume for conditional proof, i.e. P is true at some t in D
3. P
   ◊-Elimination on line 2, i.e. index at t1 where P is true
4. P→Q
   □-Elimination on line 1, i.e. at t1 since P→Q true at any t in D
5. Q
   MP on lines 3 and 4, at t1
6. ◊Q
   ◊P-Introduction on line 5, at t1
7. ◊P→◊Q
   Discharge ◊P for conditional proof
8. □(P→Q)→◊P→◊Q
   Discharge □(P→Q) for conditional proof

Note, in one of the comments it was suggested proving □P→◊P might help. Here's a proof of that:

1. □P
   Assume for conditional proof
2. P
   □-Elimination on line 1, at time t2
3. ◊P
   ◊-Introduction on line 2, at t2
4. □P→◊P
   Discharge □P for conditional proof

Then by substitution, you can infer □(P→Q)→◊(P→Q). Call this **T-Replacement**. But I don't think that would be useful in proving □(P→Q)→◊P→◊Q. To see why, suppose you've inferred ◊(P→Q) from □(P→Q) by T-Replacement. Then:

1. ◊(P→Q)
   From T-Replacement
2. ◊P
   Assume for conditional proof
3. P
   ◊-Elimination on line 2, i.e. index at t3 where P→Q is true
4. P→Q
   ◊-Elimination on line 1, i.e. index at *t4* where P→Q is true

But you can't combine lines 3 and 4 to use MP since they're indexed to different times. I don't think you can infer ◊P→◊Q from ◊(P→Q).

Comment: I don't think  □P→◊P is valid (perhaps it is in LTL?).  But if a state `t1` has no successor, then □P is true for every P, and ◊P is true for no P.

Comment: I was assuming every t has a unique successor. Without that, there are bigger problems, it seems. If it's possible for a t1 to have no successor, then you can't prove □(P→Q)→(P→Q). But then I don't think you can prove ◊P→◊Q from □(P→Q).

Comment: True, but the validity of the original statement would still hold: □(P→Q)→(◊P→◊Q).

Comment: @PålGD □P→◊P is valid in LTL, every state has a successor in LTL but even if we allow states with no successors then ◊P is true if  □P because the future states referenced by the ◊ operator include the present state. (Michael Huth, Mark Ryan: Logic in Computer Science)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2 methods to prove validity of $\Phi$:

1. Proof by contradiction. Assume we can falsify $\Phi$, prove that actually it is impossible to achieve.The clue in https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/101284/88420 shows how to do it.
2. Assume $\Phi$ valid, prove the unsatisfiability of $\neg \Phi$. Using a calculi probably we should derive $\phi \wedge \neg \phi$. A tool can confirm it, but I couldn't derive it by hand.